# Intel Arc Control, always when starting the PC

Tags: intel

Intel Arc Control, always when starting the PC I asked to make changes, does anyone know why?[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Intel should do sth with that.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 11

Go to the 'task manager', then 'Startup apps', and then 'Disable' the 'Intel Arc Control' line.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Arc Control just gets added to your Start-up folder menu.  Just remove it from %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup or C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.
The program is trying to make changes that need admin privileges when it starts up, which means it needs approval because you have User Account Control configured as default.
I just removed Intel Arc Control from my startup folder to stop the error. It's still there if you want to run it manually.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the Intel driver updater to install and re-enable ARC on each update?